# off-season time period calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if the "off-season" or "dead" is the correct definition in my question. Anyway, here is the explanation:

Having `$period['from']` and `$period['to']` in my array, i need to calculate the "dead or off-season" periods in the year 2013.

Example input periods:

```
From            To
2013-04-01      2013-06-01
2013-07-15      2013-07-20
2013-09-01      2013-10-31
```

and the dead-periods will be (output):

```
From            To
2013-01-01      2013-03-31
2013-06-02      2013-07-14
2013-07-21      2013-08-31
2013-11-10      2013-12-31
```

I am totally stuck with this.
Any help would be appreciated,

Karls

Comment: You've tagged this MySQL. Does this mean you want to do this in SQL or solely in PHP?

Comment: Can the input periods overlap?

Comment: The data is in MySQL but i am working in PHP. Better in PHP.

Comment: No overlapped input periods.

Comment: What do you have so far? It does not seem that complicated...

Comment: In MySQL, the simplest approach is to construct a calendar table of all possible dates, and then just OUTER JOIN onto that to get your result. Alternatively, in PHP, you can just construct a loop of dates and compare that with the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function dateDiff(array $dates, $startAt = null, $endAt = null) {
    if ($startAt === null) {
        $startAt = date("Y-01-01");
        $start = strtotime($startAt) - 86400;
    } else {
        $start = strtotime($startAt);
    }        

    if ($endAt === null) {
      $endAt = date("Y-12-31");
    }

    $result = array();

    foreach ($dates as $row) {
        $to = strtotime($row['from']);      
        $result[] = array('from' => date('Y-m-d', $start + 86400), 'to' => date('Y-m-d', $to - 86400));
        $start = strtotime($row['to']);;
    }
    $result[] = array('from' => date('Y-m-d', $start + 86400), 'to' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endAt)));

    return $result;
}



$dates = array(
    array('from' => '2013-04-01', 'to' => '2013-06-01'),
    array('from' => '2013-07-15', 'to' => '2013-07-20'),
    array('from' => '2013-09-01', 'to' => '2013-10-31'),
);

print_r(dateDiff($dates));
```

This will produce:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [from] => 2013-01-01 [to] => 2013-03-31 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [from] => 2013-06-02 [to] => 2013-07-14 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [from] => 2013-07-21 [to] => 2013-08-31 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [from] => 2013-11-01 [to] => 2013-12-31 ) 
)
```

Comment: Jakub, with input perioids: 2013-01-01 - 2013-03-31 & 2013-04-01 - 2013-08-31 & 2013-09-01 - 2013-12-31 i'am getting off-periods: 2013-01-01 - 2012-12-31 & 2013-04-01 - 2013-03-30 & 2013-09-01 - 2013-08-31 & 2014-01-01 - 2013-12-31
is anything you can advise to fix this?